# How to remove $promise and $resolved from json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using $resource in angular to get json object and its structure is defined below

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Type1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Type 2"
    }
]
```

after fetching the data .. console.log(jsonObject) gives me

```
[Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
```

How can I remove  $promise & $resolved from the resulting object ?
I tried angular.fromJson(json) but still I see that these objects still exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does angular $resource add extra objects ($promise, $resolve...) to my data response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548161/why-does-angular-resource-add-extra-objects-promise-resolve-to-my-data)

Comment: user1184100 can you accept one of answers below?

Comment: @javarome points solutions down below: you can clean a single result object with `toJSON`function. If the result is an array, you can clean it with map `var cleanList = result.map(function(e){return e.toJSON();})`

Answer (score 9):

I'm looking for the same answer, but at this moment I know only this ugly hack:

To write a func like this:

```
function cleanResponse(resp) {
    return JSON.parse(angular.toJson(resp));
}
```

and call it in every single query (ugly, yep):

```
function getSmt() {
    Resource.get({}, function (data) {
        $scope.some = cleanResponse(data);
    }, function (responce) {
        //handle error
    })
}
```

I'll be happy if someone would teach me how to do it correctly

Comment: And yes, if you need to put a pure json object in (for example) localStorage, you may use angular.toJson() method

Comment: This is not the optimized way to do it. The promise object already has toJSON() function in its prototype. So you just need `resp.toJSON()` and get the object without extra fields.

Answer (score 4):

Example from my project

```
Diary.getSharedWithMe(function(data) {
        delete data.$promise;
        delete data.$resolved;
        _self.sharedDiariesWithMe = data;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548161/why-does-angular-resource-add-extra-objects-promise-resolve-to-my-data#answer-29020361), it looks that `yourResource.toJSON()` is readily available.

Answer (score 3):

Right, I've faced the same problem several times and always ended up using $http instead of $resource, **however**, today I decided to try and deal with this issue. I hope somebody will find this useful one day as well.

So, after you receive your object with $promise inside of it, what you do is just use `angular.copy(data)`, like so:

```
someService.getSomething($scope.someId).$promise.then(function (data) {
    if (data) {
        $scope.dataWithoutPromise = angular.copy(data);
    }
});
```

After that, you will see that your `dataWithoutPromise` just contains the objects that you need, and $promise and $resolved are gone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue. In fact, you simply have to use the same version of angular and angular-resource and it will work like a charm.
Hope it helps !

Comment: This didnt help the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(resp));
This will remove all "angular specific" functions etc and will return you a clean data object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `isArray` or `.query()` with your `$resource` object?

From the $resource docs: `isArray – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this action is an array.`

UPDATE:

If you are using `$resource` correctly, some options you have are:

1) Have the backend return the data contained within an object, eg. `{ data: [] }` rather than  just an array.

2) If that is not possible, use the callback from the `$resource.query()`, eg.

```
MyResource.query({ myParams: 'something'}, function(result) {
    // Do something with the plain result
});
```

Comment: My mapping looks like this.. { 'get':    {method:'GET'},
     'save':   {method:'POST'},
     'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
     'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
     'delete': {method:'DELETE'},
     'jsonp' :  {method:'JSONP'},
     'put' : {method:'PUT'}
     
      }
    ); and I use query() to fetch

Comment: I also would have wanted it in { data : []} but that's not possible now since the backend is already defined and I already use callback.. var typeService = restService.async(url);
        typeService({},function(u, getResponseHeaders) {
         console.log(u);
        }, function(error) {
        }); and u returns $promise and $resource

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I did this quick reusable method for [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)  (Properties with leading $$ will be stripped):

```
yourApp.factory('Service', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('your/rest/api/path');
}]);

 yourApp.factory('commonServices', function () { 
         return {
                toJson : function(response){
                    return JSON.parse(angular.toJson(response));
                     //*or* 
                    //return angular.toJson(response);
                }
    });
```

And then something like this in your controller:

```
 yourApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'Service','commonServices',  
function ($scope, Service, commonServices) {
            Service.get().then(function (data) {
                $scope.myData = commonServices.toJson(data);
            });
        });
```

the more simple way is to add [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) in the controller

```
 yourApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'Service',  
function ($scope, Service, commonServices) {
            Service.get().then(function (data) {
                $scope.myData = angular.toJson(data);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please simply do this:

jsonObject.$promise = undefined;
jsonObject.$resolved = undefined;

$promise and $resolved will not be removed but you will be able to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try to code something like this in your service:

```
yourApp.factory('Service', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('your/rest/api/path');
}]);
```

And then something like this in your controller:

```
yourApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'Service', function ($scope, Service) {
    Service.get().then(function (data) {
        $scope.myData = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: This will return `{$$state: Object}` as a response for `json` variable.

Comment: actually it will return `$promise: Object, $resolved: true` as author complains.