# Why does angular $resource add extra objects ($promise, $resolve...) to my data response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I return a resource with a URL

```
    $resource("http://foo.com/bar.json").get().
         $promise.then(function(data){ $scope.result = data}, 
                  function(error){ $scope.msg = "error" } );
```

Resource returns

```
["item1"...."item_n",.....,"$promise", "$resolved", "$get", "$save", "$query", "$remove", "$delete"]
```

Why do I get all those objects in my data set. I'm guessing $promise just returns all this and waits for the server response. But once I have the server response where can I just get my server data without the Promise jargon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in case someone else is stumbling here and didn't understand promises/angularjs here is what is going on. When you use `.then()` or `.get()` you get a promise and some helper functions all in the same object. This is awesome because then you don't worry about callbacks being defined and whether data is available because the promise object always has some properties. This object contains your raw data in another object within. So the promise object is nested, you just have to reference the data object within when the data is ready.

Here's what I was doing

```
     $resource("http://foo.com/bar.json").get().
         $promise.then(function(data){ $scope.result = data}, 
//data is actually a promise object.
                  function(error){ $scope.msg = "error" } );
```

promise object

[image]

Note the data is actually under another object called "data". So in your success callback to get just the data you should do in this case: `data.data`

Comment: For mine I don't see `data.data`, when using .query() i see $promise and $resolved all mixed into the same object/array.. am i missing something? It makes it a pain to loop over the result of multiple items when using .query()

Comment: Actually even you are using `get().$promise.then()` in latest versions of angular. It still send you $promise and $resolve. So you need to use data.toJSON(). 
Of course this is in case that your server uses REST

Comment: I've faced the same problem, but have an alternative solution. I've already replied for the similar questions, you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831623/how-to-remove-promise-and-resolved-from-json-object/38393141#38393141)

Answer (score 33):

If you look at the angular source here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L505

There is a toJSON method on the Resource prototype chain that will accomplish this for you.

For example:

```
$resource("http://foo.com/bar.json").get(function(res) {
    $scope.result = res.toJSON();
});
```

Comment: Same problem as @chovy and @Tallboy. Feels kludgy, but resorting to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))` gave a good result.

Comment: This is poor solution. After converting it to a JSON string, you need to parse it again. The best approach is from @callmejuggernaut http://stackoverflow.com/a/32313951/276949

Comment: @MartinKonecny `Resource#toJSON()` actually returns an object, not a string, so this answer is the correct solution.

Comment: If you are getting back an array from $resource, toJSON will not be available.

Answer (score 5):

You need to return wrapped result like {'result': { 'some_key': 'some_val' }} from your backend.
Or just do like described above.

```
Diary.getSharedWithMe(function(data) {
        delete data.$promise;
        delete data.$resolved;
        _self.sharedDiariesWithMe = data;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

`$resource` returns an object or array that will have your data when the call completes.  All those functions are there to help you out and `$resource` is mainly intended for CRUD operations.  If you want the data, you have to wait for it to get returned so you might as well use the promise.  If you want to strip all of those properties you can use [`angular.toJson`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) to convert it to json, but angular does that for you when posting it back to a resource or $http call so you shouldn't have to.

```
$scope.data = $resource("http://foo.com/bar.json").get();
// $scope.data does not have your data yet, it will be
// populated with your data when the AJAX call completes
...
// later in a call from a save button maybe you can just do
// this to post your changes back:
$scope.data.$save();
```

Comment: angular.toJson works, thanks. but I want to also flatten the data and get the keys and angular.toJson seems to not work with common flat functions.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically remove them from every request, you can add an interceptor:

```
angular.module('app').config(config);

config.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
function config($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
}

interceptor.$inject = [];
function interceptor() {
    return {
        request: (config) => {
            if (config.data) {
                delete config.data.$promise;
                delete config.data.$resolved;
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
}
```